# Parse cloud not deleting more than 1000 records

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

i am writing a code on my parse cloud function.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function (request, response) {
{
    var query = new Parse.Query('ShowData');
    query.limit(1000);
    query.equalTo('userID', request.params.userID);
    query.find().then(function (results) {
        if (results.length == 1000) {
            Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
            Parse.Cloud.run("test", request, response);
        } else {
            Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
            return response.success("done");
        }
    });
});
```

Technically it should delete more than 1k users, but for some reason it's not. It is deleting only 1000 records. What can be the error possible in my logic? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [parse JS SDK guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions), `Parse.Cloud.run` accepting parameters are like:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('averageStars', { movie: 'The Matrix' }).then(function(ratings) {
     // ratings should be 4.5
});
```

So you pass:

1. the name of your cloud function
2. an object as parameters